# Is it possible to decrypt Outlook Web App S/MIME messages in a web browser with same webclient?

Tags: smartcard, smime

Normally, you would use a mail client for mail encryption. Though, I can access smartcard security functions from the browser for a secure login.

Therefore, is it possible to decrypt *Outlook Web App* S/MIME messages using same client in a web browser like Chrome/Firefox? OS is Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: "in a web browser" - do you mean a web-based email client like Gmail? How are you planning on accessing the email?

Comment: @schroeder both sender and receiver are Outlook Web App clients. Thanks, I've extended the question to make it clear.

Comment: That doesn't clarify. What does "same webclient" mean?

Comment: do you mean like this? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/exchange-server-2007/bb691090(v=exchg.80)

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what it is you want. My guess is that this is more of an Outlook config thing and not a security question. Either this should be asked of Microsoft or you need to piece together something with the parts you have, which means this is more of a SuperUser question.